# From key details to key resource

Tags: php, php-openssl

I use the function `openssl_pkey_get_details` to get the details of my keys (primes, exponents...).
Key types I managed are mostly RSA and EC ones.

Example:

```
<?php
$pemFilename = 'file://'.__DIR__ . '/public.es256.key';
$keyResource = openssl_pkey_get_public($pemFilename);
$details = openssl_pkey_get_details($keyResource);
```

With the code above, the data contained in the `$details` is an array with the components of my key.

Now I would like to convert back this array into a key resource i.e. the inverse function of the one above.

Example:

```
$keyResource = function_to_be_defined($details);
```

Is there any way to do it without external libraries?

The comments recommend to use function `openssl_pkey_get_private`, but it accepts only the file path to a PEM key or a string that contains the key in PEM format.

Comment: [openssl_pkey_get_private](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-private.php) if you have the private key already, which you do.

Comment: I updated the question as I am not sure the previous version was clear enough. `openssl_pkey_get_private` is not what I need.

Comment: Quote: `Now I would like to convert back those details into a key resource`. Quote from manual of `openssl_pkey_get_private` - `resource openssl_pkey_get_private ( mixed $key [, string $passphrase = "" ] )`. Now, you are obviously far better off explaining what you're after, as you want to do something with that "resource". We've got an XY problem here.

Comment: AFAIK there is no method that accepts an array with key components and returns a resource. You have to convert your array into a key in PEM format and then load it as you already do.